# MAUI UserAppTheme settings not apply to Picker/Searchbar

Tags: picker, maui, textcolor

Environment: VS 17.4 preview 1, Windows10, System Theme : Dark

To reproduce the bug:

1, Create a new Maui program.

2, added a line

```
        Application.Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Light;
```

to App.xaml.cs file

3, in mainpage.xaml, build a picker and a searchbar like this:

```
    <StackLayout>
        <Border Stroke="Red">
            <Picker>
                <Picker.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>Item1</x:String>
                        <x:String>Item2</x:String>
                        <x:String>Item3</x:String>
                    </x:Array>
                </Picker.ItemsSource>
            </Picker>
        </Border>
        <Border Stroke="Blue">
            <SearchBar WidthRequest="300"
                       HeightRequest="50"
                       Placeholder="input search text"
                       TextColor="Blue" />
        </Border>
    </StackLayout>
```

4, Make sure your system is in Dark theme.

5, Start the program.

you can see, the picker is still in dark panel; if you move mouse over the picker, the text color is changed to WHITE, looks like it disappeared.
The searchbar button is disappeared because it's white.

Comment: Could you create a new MAUI project for testing? It is working on my side. Do you have Styles' for ContentPage or Picker?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I have changed my question to another one. you can read the post again. 我发现问题其实是picker和searchbar不响应强制theme设置，请重新看一下问题描述。

Comment: Now I can reproduce this issue, No matter I set `TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=Green, Dark=Green}"` this text will be white, I found a known issue:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6596

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Added fix for windows and android.

**For Windows** 
Set the RequestedTheme property in Platforms > Windows > App.xaml to 'Light' or 'Dark'. 
Remember to set the `Application.Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Light;` as well for your app along with the below cha

```
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication
    x:Class="NetMaui.WinUI.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:maui="using:Microsoft.Maui"
    RequestedTheme="Light"
    xmlns:local="using:NetMaui.WinUI">

</maui:MauiWinUIApplication>
```

**For Android** 
I've made a video, which might be what you're after. Had the same issue.
This code needs to go in your MainApplication.cs under Android platform folder.

```
AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;
```

https://youtu.be/7Rqq8LrdkO8

Comment: I encountered this situation under windows. have you tried this under windows?

Comment: very good answer. btw, where did you find this property? any document or resources?

Comment: Sometimes you just need to put 2 and 2 together. Behind the scenes, MAUI converts its code to platform specific code. So the logic is, if MAUI can't do it, find out what needs to be done within the platform-specific folder. This led me to WIN docs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.application.requestedtheme?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3